# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable after using sorted function (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, iterable

So I'm writing this code to see if an element in a list could be removed to make the list increasing.
in the code below why do I get this error?

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    sorted_sequence = sorted(sequence)
    counter = 0
    for i in len(sequence):
        if sorted_sequence[i] != sequence[i]:
            counter += 1
    if counter > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Look again at `for i in len(sequence)`.  `len(sequence)` is a number.  You probably mean `range(len(sequence))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(sequence)` is a number here, and you can't iterate a number:

```
for i in len(sequence):
    ...
```

You probably wanted

```
for a,b in zip(sequence, sorted_sequence):
    ...
```

You may as well return the count rather than a boolean, or return from within the for-loop, since it's not necessary to iterate the entire sequence to check whether this count is > 1.